# AWS codepipeline run mysql import script to seed RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-codepipeline

I am working on a cloudformation template that includes a codepipeline to setup various parts of the stack (ecr / ecs server and RDS instance).

The idea is to setup a staging environment.

I have a set of business logic such as products on sale that I need to reseed the RDS instance with each time a rebuild is triggered by a git push.

I have some sql scripts that will wipe / insert data but for the life of me cannot run the script as part of the codepipeline / codebuild.

I have a buildspec.yml file that I run other commands from just I cant get this one to run.

```
sql-setup:
    user: ${CURRENT_UID}
    restart: "no"
    image: mariadb:latest
    working_dir: /
    command: mysql -u$USERNAME -p$PASSWORD < sql_script.sql
    volumes:
      - ../../sql-scripts/:/sql-scripts/
```

Can someone advise me on this please as I am stuck.

Comment: Which command(s) fail and what error message do you see?

Comment: @aaron I have added a code snippet. There are no errors yet but I am trying to run this .yml via a docker-compose exec. It appears to be dropping into mysqld

Comment: Is this meant to be a CodeBuild buildspec? I'm not sure what it means to run it via a Docker command. Have you tried adding a CodeBuild action to your pipeline?